# Azerothcore and Mod-Playerbots from ZhengPeiRu21

Tags: github, cmake, module, patch, azerothcore

Having trouble compiling Azerothcore with Playerbots .

1. Cmake / Compile perfectly without the module or with other one .
2. Cloned this branch:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/azerothcore-wotlk.git --branch Playerbot --single-branch
   ```
3. Cloned this fork:  https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/mod-playerbots.git
4. Keep getting 2 Failed

Screenshot :
[Playerbots compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju2X5.png)
[Playerbots error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57lIf.png)

I've been trying for 3 days and can't figure it out anyone willing to help me or give me some guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage **images** which represent textual information. Please, [edit] your post and paste the error message as **text**. See also [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the modified azerothcore that is linked in the description of playerbots? You cannot use the main repository for azerothcore with playerbots

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).